# Firebug console: not showing console.log

Tags: javascript, html, firebug, console.log

I am trying to test something, and for one reason or another, while working in the Firebug console, I am unable to create an array of script tags on the HTML page using the `getElementByTagName('script')` method. I realize there is probably something stupid I am overlooking.

This is the dummy HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Random Crapolla Page</title>
    <h1>Random Crapolla Page</h1>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="whyNot">
    <p id="p1">
        <a href="http://google.com">Here is link one</a><br />
        <a href="http://google.com">Oh poop here's another</a><br />
        <a href="http://google.com">And a 3rd for good measure</a><br />
    </p>

    <a id="p2">
        Latin. Latin. Latin...<br />
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
    </p>
    </div>
    <!-- Script tag testing-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="itDoesntExist.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dummyJSnumeroDos.js"></script>
</body>
```

And this is what I'm typing into the Firebug console:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
console.log(scripts);
```

[image]

---

All selected in Console
[image]

Comment: At the top of your question, you have `getElementByTagName('scripts')` *(plural scripts)*, and at the bottom you correctly have `getElementByTagName('script')`. Which are you actually using?

Comment: @cookiemonster my output is nothing. And i am using 'script'.

Comment: It should be `document.getElementsByTagName('script');`, note the plural in Elements, and script as singular. It should work. An alternative might be `document.querySelectorAll('script')`

Comment: @Matias - it is singular 'script' :/ both methods created no output

Comment: As long as the code is exactly as you show at the bottom, you should get at least *something* for the output. You're saying that absolutely nothing shows up in the console?

Comment: @cookiemonster No such luck :/ included a picture of what i'm doing

Comment: I'll apologize in advance for this question, but you're clicking the `Run` button, right? *(Sorry.)*

Comment: @cookiemonster yeah. i also noticed i didn't put the ending ";", but that did not help either

Comment: Console and All mode?

Comment: @progysm yeah. just put a picture in the question of how i'm selecting all

Comment: **As of end of 2016. year firebug is no longer maintained or developed** as it says on their web-page https://getfirebug.com

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have *info* selected, it will only show info. Click the *All* button!

[image]

And to show that it makes a difference, new screenshots

[image]

Comment: The last image OP posted shows that all are enabled. But either way, `info` shows `console.log()` output, doesn't it? I haven't used Firebug in a while.

Comment: Ah, `console.info()`. Makes sense. +1

Comment: @cookiemonster Added a new screenshots to show you it does matter.

Comment: Please see the other answer. Still was using Firebug, did miss that it is discontinued...

Comment: This should not be the correct answer, newer version of Firefox have integrated dev tools, like Chrome.

Comment: @AlexisWilke The question is about "Firebug Console" is not not firefox console.

Comment: I see this was 2014 and back then that was certainly the correct answer. Today the console stopped working as Firebug is not being maintained and there is an error preventing the `console.js` from doing anything good.

Answer (score 54):

Firebug is [officially discontinued](https://getfirebug.com/) now and the console output is broken in Firefox 51.0.1 due to a change in the Firefox internal APIs Firebug uses to access the related data. For reference, this is the error:

> TypeError: ConsoleAPIListener is not a constructor  console.js:149:38

Firebug users are advised to switch over to the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) instead. There, the console output works as expected.

Comment: Actually, if you have a current enough version, you can right click and see whether you have an "Inspect Element (Q)" option. If so, you have a version with the new feature, including the console output.

Comment: Note that the "Inspect Element (Q)" option opens the Firefox DevTools. And that option already exists for several years now.

Answer (score 13):

Press CTRL-SHIFT-K to open full console. In the second row from the top there are tabs- NET, CSS, JS ... Logging. click on the dropdown next to logging and make sure that at least "log" is on.

Your messages should be visible now. Use this instead of CTRL+SHIFT+J

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but I'm a huge fan of `Firebug`, and I don't like the `Firefox dev tools` tool (inspect element).

I downgraded Firefox to version `50.1.0`, and I see the console.log msgs back.
https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/50.1.0/

Hope that helps other fans ...

Comment: I've outlined more alternatives in [another answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41890636/432681). Downgrading should just be a temporary solution, as you're missing important security updates and other improvements. Btw. the last version of Firefox where everything of Firebug works should be 48.0.