# Firebug toolbar button is always shown deactivated since Firefox 51.0.1

Tags: firefox, firebug

Recently my Firefox got updated to version 51.0.1. Initially it was showing some reminder check (I'm not clear with that) related to Firebug, but I ignored it. Now, the Firebug toolbar button is always shown deactivated.

[image: Inactive Firebug button]

I've reinstalled Firebug several times, but the result is always the same.

Is there any compatibility issue? How do I activate Firebug?

Comment: That the Firebug button stays gray after opening the tools is a known bug, which I've linked to in my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why got Firebug removed after updating Firefox to version 50?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40744448/why-got-firebug-removed-after-updating-firefox-to-version-50)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52083590/5717031

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There is a solution to use Firebug version 2.0.18 in the latest version of Firefox (this time 51.0.1).

To enable the old Firebug:

In the address bar, enter *about:config* and
find *browser.tabs.remote.autostart*. Set it to false.

Also set *browser.tabs.remote.autostart.1*
and *browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2* to false.

Comment: Working very well, thanks! You just saved me from never using Firefox for development again (10+ years dedicated user). The inspector is a slow, painful, annoying headache to use.

Answer (score 3):

This is the new version of Firefox, and it is not working as intended and making the life of developers & designers even more difficult... look at the review,  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/reviews/?page=1.

This actually is Firefox DevTools as Firebug is no longer supported for future developments.

You can install the previous version to work with. I installed it and my problem was solved. I have my old version back...
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/versions/.

New version of it comes with some new features, but some handy features are also left out. It looks totally new to me. May be one day I have to get used to it. For now one can revert back to the old version.

Comment: You are right It seems too tedious to work with. Is any alternative available  ?

Comment: Check my updated answer it should  solve your problem. I installed version 2.0.17

Comment: If it works then mark my answer as correct as this could help other user also

Comment: Thanks Its working. Just update the older version links. You last link redirecting on latest version. :)

Comment: There are more alternatives than reverting to an older version of Firebug. I've linked those with additional information on what happened and what to do in my answer.

Comment: For clarification, the "new version" is *not* Firebug but the Firefox DevTools. And your answer doesn't clarify why the Firebug toolbar button stays gray when it's clicked.

Comment: @SebastianZartner, Agree with you. I had mentioned it as FF and later while editing again i changed it to FB, i will correct it

Comment: Both links are broken: *"Oops! We can’t find that page"*

Answer (score 1):

This is because Firebug is integrated into the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) once [multi-process Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox) is enabled, and it doesn't track the enabled state of those tools. This is a [known bug](https://github.com/firebug/firebug.next/issues/370).

Note that a click on the Firebug button with multi-process Firefox enabled actually opens the Firefox DevTools with a Firebug theme trying to make the transition a bit easier, because Firebug is [officially discontinued](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/).

If you want the old Firebug back and by that make the Firebug button work again as expected, you need to disabled multi-process Firefox as explained in an [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40910225/432681) by going to `about:config` and setting the preferences `browser.tabs.remote.autostart`, `browser.tabs.remote.autostart.1` and `browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2` to `false`. Though note that this is just a temporary workaround, because multi-process Firefox will be mandatory at some point.

Furthermore, the Firefox DevTools offer a lot more features than Firebug, but they are also lacking some Firebug had. Therefore, a [bug is filed to close those gaps](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=991806).

In the [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41890636/432681) I've listed what your alternatives are.

If you want to stay with the Firefox DevTools, there is a [migration guide for Firebug users](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Migrating_from_Firebug).

Answer (score 1):

Firebug seems to have activated for me after I got the [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/web-developer/) Add-On on Firefox.

Comment: Funny.. I tried all the other things to no avail. THIS however was the only thing that actually worked for me! It also extended the firebug button in the menu bar so that I could work with it again. Thanks so much! Works with FF 54.0.1 (64-bit) and last Firebug version. You can disable Web Developer plugin afterwards btw... just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Open the default Element Inspector, and click the settings icon.

Under the **Themes** section, you will see the *Light* option is checked. Change it to **Firebug**. Firebug will be activated automatically.

[image]

Comment: For me it didn't activate it. Only the theme changed

Answer (score 0):

The best way to install [FirePath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992056/why-doesnt-firepath-work-anymore-since-firefox-51-0-1) and Firebug is to downgrade Firefox by downloading an older version of Firefox , like 31 from Firefox ftp.

I downloaded older version of Firefox from http://mozilla_firefox.en.downloadastro.com/old_versions/

After downgrading, go to menu *option* → *Update and check "Never check for updates"* checkbox

```
If the below setting has been made:

In address enter about:config, find
browser.tabs.remote.autostart set it false
browser.tabs.remote.autostart.1 set it false
browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2 set it false
```

Then reset firefox by typing 'about:support' in the address bar

Click *"Reset Firefox"*

By doing this, you should be able to install the FirePath and Firebug addons from the Mozilla addons page.

Comment: Why would you trust `downloadastro.com`?