# Firebug is showing deactivated

Tags: eclipse, selenium, firebug

I had installed firebug and run a WebDriver program on eclipse.
On running the code, page shows the URL but not the Firebug Icon.
Also on opening browser manually Firebug is showing deactivated and I'm unable to inspect element by using Firebug.

using Firefox Version :- 45.0
eclipse version :- 4.5
WebDriver version :2.51
FireBug version :- 2.0.19

Comment: Can you consider showing us your work please? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 Problems

> 1. After running selenium code firebug icon is not there :

Selenium creates new profile every time while run the script. Thats why it won't show your addons, plugins, bookmarks in that browser

Your add on only will display in profile you are using e.g. manually opening the browser You can add thet profile in your selenium code then you will be able to view all your addons, bookmarks and all

[This](http://www.guru99.com/firefox-profile-selenium-webdriver.html) is tutorial link frome where you can learn.

> 2. Disable firebug icon

I was also getting that firebu icon desable issue before few day in FF version 51 . either your ff version and firebug version not compitable . Please have a look in this question

[Firebug toolbar button is always shown deactivated since Firefox 51.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41929647/firebug-toolbar-button-is-always-shown-deactivated-since-firefox-51-0-1)

Comment: I would like to disagree a bit on `Selenium creates new profile every time` as each & every browser does it a bit differently. As of Mozilla Firefox the config we provide overrides the default settings and acts as a template unitll and unless we explicitly mention about starting/creating an/a existing/new Profile. Thanks

Comment: I have a confusion:- In the 1st part of your answer:- is it means we cannot use firebug in Selenium as it will not show any add on. Also in the 2nd part I am using Firefox 45(degraded the version)

Comment: For 1st  point : Not like that- you have to use the same profile(firebug installed ) by setting up profile configuration in your code. Just go through the tutorial which i have shared the link. you will get the clear idea.   For 2nd point Either you can try the solution which is the answer of given link or downgrade your firebug version. Let me know incase any help or confusion

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

You can't get Firebug Extension added to the Firefox Session started by WebDriver anymore.

The reason behind is:

Question for you: **`Is your extension signed?`** The Answer is **"No"**.

So according to [MDN](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Add-ons/Extension_Signing), **"Firefox 48: (Pushed from Firefox 46). Release and Beta versions of Firefox for Desktop will not allow unsigned extensions to be installed, with no override.**

So to install an unsigned extension you'll need to downgrade Firefox to 47.x Legacy release versions.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: I am using Firefox 45.