# Firepath is not working on lasted version in mozilla

Tags: selenium-webdriver

unable to access the source code using firepath for  lasted version in mozilla.
can any one please help me on that.

thanks,
Suraj

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebug toolbar button is always shown deactivated since Firefox 51.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41929647/firebug-toolbar-button-is-always-shown-deactivated-since-firefox-51-0-1)

Comment: It is deactivated after firefox version 51.0.1, degrade the firefox and selenium version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is deactivated after firefox version 51.0.1 , you have to see this links of official Firefox.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/reviews/?page=1

if still you want to use it, FF 45.0 and 48.0, I am working on it and it is working fine