# Firebug latest version 2.0.19 is not showing HTML in latest version of Mozilla Firefox 56 button

Tags: firefox, firebug

[image: Please note that no HTML is rendering when I inspect element in fire path.]

[I have followed this link as well But it didn't work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41929647/firebug-toolbar-button-is-always-shown-deactivated-since-firefox-51-0-1/41941793#41941793%5C]%5C[1%5C])

Answer (score 2):

[Firebug has been discontinued and is no longer supported](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/10/saying-goodbye-to-firebug/).

Firefox users should use the [Firefox Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) instead.