# Full iframe path to an element

Tags: css, selenium, iframe, xpath, automated-tests

The application I'm testing is very complex. It has dozens of tabs and thousands of fields. For my tests I need to access ~150 fields.

I'm going through the process of collecting the necessary information to access the elements: xpath, id, css selector, etc. All of these elements sit inside of iframes, sometimes as many as 4 nested iframes. I'm using Firefox to inspect the elements and there is an easy way to get the xpath, css selector, etc. However, in order to figure out what iframe an item is in I have to look through the path in the scrolling bar at the bottom of the inspector window. This is working, my code works, but it's tremendously tedious and has the potential to introduce errors if I miss an iframe.

The question is: is there a way to get the list of iframes that wrap around an element that is easier/faster than the manual investigation that I'm doing now? Possibly something similar to the copy xpath, etc. that is built in to the inspection tool. I'm open to both ideas and applications/extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Once you open the firepath as mentioned in below image :

[image]

If you see on top left corner it showing top window, Just click on it, It will show you all the frame present in your web page and once you select any frame then it also show that frams' html as well.

As shown in below image, the frame get highlighted once mouse over on that frame

[image]

So here you can easily identify your element is in which frame.

And once you move pointer to the element it will automatically shows that frame as selected where your element is. As shown here.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the answer, the problem is that firepath is deprecated and can not be installed on current versions of Firefox. They did a pretty good job of integrating features from FirePath and FireBug, but I haven't found this one. For reference I'm using Firefox Developer Edition ver. 57.0b12 (64-bit)

Comment: Yes you are right. for that you can downgrade your FF version to make compatible with firebug. You can also look at here might be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41929647/firebug-toolbar-button-is-always-shown-deactivated-since-firefox-51-0-1