# Firebug showing wrong UI

Tags: firefox, firebug

I am facing a strange issue related to Firebug in my Firefox.

I have Mozilla firefox installed (51.0.1 [32-bit]) in my Windows machine and I have Firebug 2.0.18 installed, but when I click the Firebug button to open it up, it is sometimes showing the default developer tools which Firefox provides. Below are the screenshots to look at what I am getting:

[image: Firefox developer tools UI]

But I want something like this:

[image: Firebug UI]

Can someone guide me what to do to enable the previous UI of Firebug again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug is [officially discontinued](https://getfirebug.com/). You were automatically switched to the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools), because with the Firefox update [multi-process Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox) was enabled for you.

You can get Firebug to work again temporarily (until multi-process Firefox is mandatory) by changing a preference. See [my answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40910225/432681) how to do that.
I've also explained the [alternatives to the Firefox DevTools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41890636/432681).

If you want to give them a try, you should read the [migration guide for Firebug users](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Migrating_from_Firebug).

There is a [blog post on Mozilla Hacks](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/) explaining the details.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for info and sharing the stuff. However i ended up with installing older version as of now :) Thank you