# Firebug not working in Mozilla Firefox version 56

Tags: firefox

I am using Firefox 56. After auto update of Firefox to version 56, Firebug has stopped working Is there any patch to use Firebug on Firefox 56 version?

Comment: https://getfirebug.com/

Comment: Thanks a Lot mate For your valuable comment. I am using the current version of firebug. still i get the same issue.

Comment: Most of Firebug is now built into the Firefox native console

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firebug is no longer supported by Firefox browser 56.0.
You might need to look out for alternatives like Firefox Developer Tools/use older versions of Firefox with its compatible firebug version :-(

[image: Firebug-incompatible with Firefox 56.0]

Comment: Thanks mate. For your Valuable comment

Comment: You are welcome,Siva Ganesh :-)

Comment: Any alternative solution ?

Comment: Refer this article:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41889775/what-are-the-alternatives-to-the-firefox-developer-tools for alternatives.