# How else can I review the responsiveness of a local hosted app without using dev tools?

Tags: devtools, responsiveness, google-developer-tools

I'm working on an app on my machine and run it on local host. Sometimes browsers dev tools are not accurate and once I am making the changes in my code and then run, it doesn't look like how it was in dev tools. I'm talking about some alignment, responsiveness, not about styling, colors etc.

When I am comparing my app in different browsers it doesn't look the same in all of them, so I'm no sure which one is actually the accurate view.
I have tried Edge, Opera, Mozilla, Chrome. My company is monitoring my pc, so I can't install random stuff on it.

Is there any other option to preview accurately my app? Any extension or some site?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use other browsers like Opera which has developer mode, as well as, Microsoft Edge and Safari that offer web development tools. As for the alternatives for Firefox, I believe it was already answered, check this: [What are the alternatives to the Firefox Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41889775/what-are-the-alternatives-to-the-firefox-developer-tools)

Moreover, these might not directly solve your problem but if you are looking for plugins or apps, check these useful tools out:   [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/), [Percy](https://percy.io/), [Ghost Inspector](https://ghostinspector.com/landing/browser-testing/?gclid=CjwKCAjw2bmLBhBREiwAZ6ugo1DUNAl90Epz6UPDo62YolpZxLKbT4h4pjKdbFZQa_sR8say6ooCzRoCFAcQAvD_BwE), [Requestly](https://requestly.io/).

Comment: Thanks, Sadig. When I am comparing side by side my app on different browsers they don't look the same on all of them, so that's the issue I have. I have thought it will look the same. I'll try your suggestions and see how it goes. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome, happy to help a fellow learner. I'd be happy if you'd accepted my answer.