# Where did the console.log messages go from firebug?

Tags: firebug

console.log messages used to go to Firebug, but not they dont appear here but in "browser console". How to put them back?

Edit: here is a screenshot[image]

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [console.log() doesn't work anymore in Firebug since Firefox 51.0.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41933743/console-log-doesnt-work-anymore-in-firebug-since-firefox-51-0-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2 steps:

1. disable or (better) uninstall Firebug
2. press F12 and enjoy the console

Why: Firebug is not maintained anymore, it often becomes obsolete with new FF update. Tools already available in Firefox (F12) are inglobating it. See:

https://getfirebug.com/  <- the red message on main page

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the home page of Firebug http://getfirebug.com/

> The Firebug extension isn't being developed or maintained any longer.

[image]

To have your logs displayed you have 2 choices:

- Use Firebug on an older version of Firefox (in my case it's working with Firefox 45).
- Deactivate Firebug by tapping `about:addons` in the URL.

  [image]

  Then tape `F12` to use **Firefox DevTools** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools