# http interceptor doesn't add header with string token angular

Tags: angular, http, interceptor

I am trying to send a token in a header on every request. Firstly I tried to do more complicated things, like saving in local storage but now, here I am trying to add a damn header with a token string random and it's still not add the header. Why? This is the app.js, I let here only this:

```
'use strict';

function testInterceptor() {
 return {
    request: function(config) {
        config.headers['x-token'] = 'lalalalala';
        console.log(config);
        console.log("Aaa");
        return config;
    }
  }
}

var app = angular.module('myapp', ['oc.lazyLoad', 'LocalStorageModule', 'oc.lazyLoad', 'ngRoute', 'naif.base64', 'ui.router', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.factory('testInterceptor', testInterceptor);
app.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('testInterceptor');
});
```

In console.log it doesn't even printed anything. I also commented the authentication providers and let:

```
Default:
   Anonymous: ~
```

in security.yml

And when I try with postman or in browser to call my app, it doesn't add the header. Why am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the beow code & this is the way to send/append the token in Authorization header & then decode/check this header on server.

```
function testInterceptor() {
 return {
    request: function(config) {
         config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + 'lalalalala';
         return config;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, still nothing. When trying with postman nothing changes and I'm not sure where should I look when I send it from browser. In $_SERVER?

Comment: Can you paste your code or do you have include all files

Comment: What code? This is all the code I used for this part. And I don't want to use Bearer,but can you please explain me what is not correct in the first place?

Comment: Have you included the configuration file because as you are saying that nothing is print, so may be it happens & check whether code is running in request block or not. print anything anonymously. like console.log("Hello");

Comment: Because what i think, your code not running Otherwise it should give something like undefined

Comment: And this authorization header, from where it this? I ve got something HTTP_AUTHORIZATION = Basic 352gddhsjq72=, when debugging an url configured in apache for using some authentication. There sould be replaced or where?

Comment: Which browser r u using, is it firefox?

Comment: So that's the problem, you have n't seen the console.log. check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41933743/console-log-doesnt-work-anymore-in-firebug-since-firefox-51-0-1

Comment: And also, i will recommend you to use chrome while developing as per my experience, it have great debugger to work with. But it just recommendation.

Comment: Thank you very much