# How can I get Angular $log messages to appear in FireFox/FireBug console?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox

I'm using Angular 1.6.2.  I find that messages from the $log service do not appear in the Console window for the FireFox browser with FireBug installed. (Firefox 52.0.1).

How can I get them to appear?

When I run the same Website in Chrome, IE, and Edge the $log messages appear happily.  Even the sample in the Angular documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$log) does not display a Console message in my FireFox.

Comment: I don't think it is related.  That Q refers to browser different layouts of a stack trace when an error occurs.  My browser difference is that I get no output at all from a $log call in the FireFox browser.

Answer (score 0):

Buried in the answers to this Question ([Firebug console: not showing console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512855/firebug-console-not-showing-console-log)) is

> Firebug is officially discontinued now and the console output is broken in Firefox 51.0.1 due to a change in the Firefox internal APIs Firebug uses to access the related data....Firebug users are advised to switch over to the Firefox DevTools instead. There, the console output works as expected.

I'm using FireFox 52.  I installed the FireFox developer edition and I can see $log messages in the console.