# FireBug console log issue

Tags: firefox, firebug

I am using `Mozilla Firefox version 52.2.0` I installed `Firebug version 2.0.19`, it is in enabled mode.

When I am trying to print console logs, Firebug console does not print any console logs. Instead when I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, it opens browser console, there I could see console logs. But I want to see console logs on Firebug console itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebug console: not showing console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512855/firebug-console-not-showing-console-log)

Comment: As I [outlined in the answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42515910/432681), Firebug is discontinued and the console is broken due to a change the Firefox APIs.